# DNN Event Module Error

Tags: events, dotnetnuke

I've installed the last version of dnn.events module for DNN 8 successfully but when try to add it in a page an error message (exception) come and show instead
please help me solve this issue:

> --Error: Events is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Unknown server tag
>   'dnn:DnnComboBox'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Unknown server
>   tag 'dnn:DnnComboBox'. ---> System.Web.HttpParseException: Unknown
>   server tag 'dnn:DnnComboBox'. ---> System.Web.HttpException: Unknown
>   server tag 'dnn:DnnComboBox'. at
>   System.Web.UI.TagPrefixTagNameToTypeMapper.System.Web.UI.ITagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String
>   tagName, IDictionary attribs) at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType2(String tagName,
>   IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) at
>   System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.GetControlType(String tagName,
>   IDictionary attribs, Boolean fAllowHtmlTags) at
>   System.Web.UI.RootBuilder.GetChildControlType(String tagName,
>   IDictionary attribs) at
>   System.Web.UI.ControlBuilder.CreateChildBuilder(String filter, String
>   tagName, IDictionary attribs, TemplateParser parser, ControlBuilder
>   parentBuilder, String id, Int32 line, VirtualPath virtualPath, Type&
>   childType, Boolean defaultProperty) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessBeginTag(Match match, String
>   inputText) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String
>   text, Encoding fileEncoding) --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   --- at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding
>   fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding
>   fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath,
>   VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal() at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>   at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider
>   buildProvider) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath) at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Events.Events.LoadModuleControl() --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a problem with older versions of the Events module because of things deprecated in DNN 8. You need the latest release

https://github.com/DNNCommunity/DNN.Events/releases

Anyone who experiences this one their own, will need to recompile the module against the DNN 8 DLLs and modify the references to DotNetNuke.Web.DLL